# Which time formate is used in ruby on rails table by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just want to know that which time format is used in ruby on rails by default. And what type of format is this? `2014-03-12 12:30:21.869018`.
This is used by default in my table.

Comment: That is UTC Timestamp

Answer (score 1):

**usually rails uses UTC timestamp**

[time formatting](http://railscasts.com/episodes/31-formatting-time)

**I think this tutorial helps you**